# Show widget when not using SSL

Tags: widgets, ssl

My wordpress site supports http and https. What I want to do is to add a widget when surfing over http that says something like "Surf this site secure" to show the visitor that I also have a secured version.

I don't want to force them to surf over SSL because I'm using a type of certificate that's not supported on Windows XP.

Now how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has built-in function for this purpose - is_ssl().
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl

So, you should edit this widget and put something like

```
if ( is_ssl() ) {

} else {
    echo 'you should use ssl';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") { 

    //your code

}
```